# alert not displaying in firefox browse while running through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to submit a form after submitting the from it should display alert whether success or failure, so that I can get the text on alert and I can assert..But when I submit the form manually(not with web driver script) it shows alert success / failure but when I try to submit the form with web driver code it's not displaying the alert and I have checked manually in browser which open through selenium web driver it's not showing alert ? What is the issue ?
I am using firefox 44 version. Here is my code:

```
public void enrollmentTc(){
      login();
      driver.findElement(By.id("EnrollForm")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("form1")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("radio1")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("customerFirstName")).sendKeys("Reddy");
      driver.findElement(By.id("customerLastName")).sendKeys("A");
      driver.findElement(By.id("commercialName")).sendKeys("Ajith");
      driver.findElement(By.id("phoneNumber")).sendKeys("5656565656");
      driver.findElement(By.id("streetAddress")).sendKeys("Nagar");
      driver.findElement(By.id("city")).sendKeys("Hyderabad");
      driver.findElement(By.id("state")).sendKeys("TS");
      driver.findElement(By.id("postalCode")).sendKeys("500028");
      driver.findElement(By.name("Save")).click();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Show how you create your WebDriver instance. So you told that you were debuging it step by step and there is no alert? Are you sure that you "save" button was clicked?

Comment: Are you sure there is only one element named "Save"?

Comment: I will go with Danis comment. Good to have a look on your driver instance. Are you using driver capability or eventFiring web driver where onAlert() you accept it ?